# Will having two connections to the same router cause any problems?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I often have to remote into my desktop PC, and recently for some reason it's disconnected from the ethernet connection a few times.

I've just got a USB WiFi adapter as a fallback, and I have both connections currently active, in the hope that if one fails, the other will remain connected:

[image]

Are there any potential problems in doing this? I have a few other devices (PC downstairs, girlfriends laptop, phone, 360, ps3, wii etc) that also connect to the router so would it be a good idea to just use one connection so I don't risk overloading it?

Many thanks

Comment: Your PC will prefer and use only one connection at a time.  So there should be no problem.

Comment: Is there anyway to set it so the default/main connection is the ethernet by the way @sawdust?

Comment: There probably is, but I don't know how.  That's why I wrote a comment rather than an answer.  And that comment is not even 100% accurate.  I think you can setup a program to use one connection, and another program to use the other connection.  E.G. a web browser usually has a config item about "connecting to the Internet".